# Passing an edittext reference to onClickListener Of A Button

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I want to pass an edit text reference to onClickListener of a button, I have different options:-
I can pass it by creating a custom class and implementing onClickListener as given below:-

```
 public class MyLovelyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener
       {

         EditText myLovelyEditText;
         public MyLovelyOnClickListener(EditText myLovelyVariable) {
              this.myLovelyVariable = myLovelyVariable;
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             String editTextValue = myLovelyEditText.getText().toString();

         }
      };

MyLovelyOnClickListener onClickListenerVar   =  new MyLovelyOnClickListener(myEditText);


ButtonVar.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerVar);
```

My intuition says the former is the correct method.

But I can also make the EditText a member variable and reference it from inside of the onClickListener. What is the problem with doing so if any?

```
ButtonVar.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     String editTextValue  =  mEditText.getText().toString();

                }
            });
```

Does the first method have any advantage compared to the second method?If yes, then what?

Comment: What's your goal with the reference?

Comment: @Opoo... It can vary.. For example, if I want to get the text from Edit text and upload it to server on click of a "Save Button"

Comment: your code please?

Comment: You can achieve that by giving Click listener anonymously with out declaring global variables or by passing edit text ref in constructor r8?

Comment: What's that? `constructor of the onClickListener of button`

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: Use the second one

Answer (score 0):

Just make the field in your Activity (or Fragment) and use that reference.

```
private EditText editText;
```

in OnCreate

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

in your onClickListener you can use:

```
editText.getText()
```